# How to perfom lazy loading data in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a Spring boot application in which I have a one to many relationship
between my category entity and my product entity. A category contains several products
and a product belongs to one and only one category.
In the database, each category contains several registered products.
The category that contains less products in database has 1000 products
I have a category of my products in database which contains 15 000 products.
At the level of my category class, I have defined the one-to-many annotation
with the product entity and I have opted for the fetch mode = FetchType.LAZY.
This only retrieves the category entity and not the product entity.
How to do for the performance problem, because I want to create a method that
retrieves for each category, all its products and loop on it.
Even if I use the fetch mode = FetchType.EAGER,
I will have the same problem, how to better use FetchType.LAZY or FetchType.EAGER
while managing well the performance problem

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Product> product;
}

@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String code;
    private double price;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_cat")
    private Category category; 
}
```

How can i solve it

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Eager fetch type with **@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)** (https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-fetchmode),
2. **JOIN FETCH** (https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-difference-join-left-join-fetch-join/)